# Pure functions: state content vs. state reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-redux

[In this pen](https://codepen.io/gnzg/pen/vZVjVW), I am having a hard time understanding why when using the push function on a newly created const (line 24) it matters whether one uses the spread operator or simply copies "state" over. How is it that replacing `[...state]` with `state` causes `state` to be overwritten with the content of `newState`?

Am I correct in assuming that it is the **reference** to state which is overwritten if state is directly passed to newState? I.e. in the case of `const newState = state`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the spread syntax goes only **one level** deep while copying an array. If you have deeper levels your so-called "copy" will only reference them, and it will not be a real copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is the section or the pen you are referencing:

```
const newState = [...state]; // copy contents of state, NOT the reference to it (state)
newState.push(action.payload);
return newState;
```

Let's look at the difference between what this code is doing now, and what it would do if `const newState = state` was used instead.

```
const newState = [...state];
```

This line creates a new array, called `newState` with the contents of `state`.  It is essentially a one liner for:

```
const newState = [];

for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    newState.push(state[i]);
}
```

When `newState.push(action.payload)` is called, the `state` array is unchanged, while `newState` has an extra element pushed into it.

```
const newState = state;
```

This line sets the variable `newState` to the same reference as `state`, so there is only one array in play.

When `newState.push(action.payload)` is called, the new element is pushed into the array, so both `newState` and `state` have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the spread operator like this will take all the items from `state` and create a new array with these items. So `state` and `newState` will reference different arrays (which have the same elements, so if one of these elements is an object and you change one of it's properties, that change will be visible in the other array). Writing `const newState = state` will result in one array and two references to that array, since you're not creating a second array anywhere.

Comment: Equally as good, would mark as answer if two were possible, thank you!